# Sort by date with null first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find documents in a collection, ordered by their date. This works, but I get the documents with `null` in the date field at the bottom, I want these first.

```
MyModel.find({ }, null, { sort: { date: -1 } }, function(err, models) {
    // Models sorted with the "largest" date first and models with null dates last
});
```

If I change the sorting to `{ date: 1 }` I do get the documents with `null` at first, but the order otherwise is reverse, which I do not want.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Apart from resorting them manually (or possibly doing a map/reduce), I don't think it's possible (see also [this documentation on how MongoDB compares different types when sorting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-natural-order)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears there's no trivial way to do this, akin to SQL's "nulls first" / "nulls last" syntax.  This feature is mentioned in this Mongo bug:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-153

Where it's looped in with the larger feature of custom sorting functions.  (I really wish this were broken out into a separate feature request because I would think implementing *only* the nulls first/last bit should be much easier than custom sorting functions and still provide a lot of value.)

Anyway, the work-around for the time being is to just query separately for the null values in addition to your existing query:

[How are null values in a MongoDB index sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267544/how-are-null-values-in-a-mongodb-index-sorted)

```
MyModel.find({ date: null });
MyModel.find({ date: { $ne: null } }).sort({ date: -1 } });
```