# Sorting Null values last in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using the following query to populate items from MongoDB, in ascending order, according to a field called sortIndex.

Sometimes though items in the DB don't have the sortIndex field. With the following query, the items with a null sortIndex are showing up at the top, and I'm wondering how to get them to show up at the bottom. Would I need two queries for this or is there a way to use one query?

```
.populate({path: 'slides', options: { sort: { 'sortIndex': 'ascending' } } })
```

Comment: Would it be a viable option to exclude those null sortIndexes or are the required for the results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267544/how-are-null-values-in-a-mongodb-index-sorted looks like you'll have to do 2 queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort into that nulls are last ordered in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084446/how-can-i-sort-into-that-nulls-are-last-ordered-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $addFields: 
        { 
            hasValue : { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$value", null ] }, 2, 1 ] },
        }
    },
])
.sort({hasValue : 1, value : 1});
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of: [How to keep null values at the end of sorting in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839945/how-to-keep-null-values-at-the-end-of-sorting-in-mongoose/50841801#50841801)

Anyway posting the same solution ...

Am not sure about the solution am about to say. I cant test this out as I dont have a mongo db set right now, but I think that you can use `<collection>.aggregate` along with `$project` and `$sort` to achieve this.

**Sample code:**

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            item: 1,
            description: { $ifNull: [ "$amount", -1*(<mimimum value>)* ] }
         }
      },
      { 
         $sort : { 
           amount : (-1 or 1 depending on the order you want)
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Hope this helps !!