# How to custom a sort query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a list document with format:

```
{ _id: 1, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 2, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 3, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 4, expiredAt: null }
{ _id: 5, expiredAt: null }
```

Current, I sorted with { expiredAt: 1} and get a results:

```
{ _id: 4, expiredAt: null }
{ _id: 5, expiredAt: null }
{ _id: 1, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 2, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 3, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
```

But I want to expiredAt value is largest when expiredAt value == null or undefined.
Expected results:

```
{ _id: 1, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 2, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 3, expiredAt: ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z") }
{ _id: 4, expiredAt: null }
{ _id: 5, expiredAt: null }
```

How to custom a sort or any way to get a result above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep null values at the end of sorting in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839945/how-to-keep-null-values-at-the-end-of-sorting-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
[
    {$addFields: {
       hasExpirationDate:  {$ne: ["$expiredAt", null]}
    }}, 
    {$sort: {
       hasExpirationDate: -1,
       expiredAt: 1
    }}
]
```

The first stage of the pipeline adds a field named hasExpirationDate to each of the documents.  This field is calculated by checking if expiredAt is not equal to null.

The second stage does the sorting. First, it sorts by the hasExpirationDate field in descending order.  Then it sorts by the expiredAt field in ascending order.