# mongoDB/mongoose: Make null values appear at end of sort while also performing search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created the following express route for my API that returns a list of videos. The list of videos can be searched and sorted by the user depending on the url parameters. Videos might not have every sort property because they come from different websites. For example, if a video is from a website that does not support likes, `likeCount` will be `null` instead of `0`. However, this means if sorting by `least_likes` videos with `null` likes will appear first in the video list, when they really should appear last in the list because they have `null` likes, not `0` likes.

I have seen [very similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154620/sorting-null-values-last-in-mongodb) asked on this topic which all recommend to use aggregation. However, my query exceeds the complexity of those in the existing questions (as it needs to be able to sort based on a selected property, search text, limit the results, etc.) and I cannot figure out how to make it compatible with aggregation.

How can I convert code below to use aggregation so if the chosen field to sort is null the video will be returned last in the list?

```
router.get('/search/:page', async function (req, res) {
    const page = parseInt(req.params.page) || 0;
    let pattern = {};
    let options = {};
    if (req.query.search) {
        pattern = { $text: { $search: req.query.search } };
        options = { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } };
    }

    let videos;
    try {
        videos = await Video.find(pattern, options)
            .select('-_id extractor id title mediumResizedThumbnailFile directory uploader videoFile uploadDate duration width height viewCount')
            .sort(sortBy(req.query['sort'], req.query.search))
            .skip(page * parsedEnv.PAGE_SIZE)
            .limit(parsedEnv.PAGE_SIZE)
            .lean()
            .exec();
    } catch (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    }

    res.json({
        videos
    });
});

const sortBy = (option, hasSearch = false) => {
    switch (option) {
        case 'relevance':
            if (hasSearch) {
                return { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } };
            } else {
                return { uploadDate: -1 };
            }
        case 'newest_date':
            return { uploadDate: -1 };
        case 'oldest_date':
            return { uploadDate: 1 };
        case 'longest_duration':
            return { duration: -1 };
        case 'shortest_duration':
            return { duration: 1 };
        case 'largest_size':
            return { 'videoFile.filesize': -1 };
        case 'smallest_size':
            return { 'videoFile.filesize': 1 };
        case 'most_views':
            return { viewCount: -1 };
        case 'least_views':
            return { viewCount: 1 };
        case 'most_likes':
            return { likeCount: -1 };
        case 'least_likes':
            return { likeCount: 1 };
        case 'most_dislikes':
            return { dislikeCount: -1 };
        case 'least_dislikes':
            return { dislikeCount: 1 };
        default:
            return { uploadDate: -1 };
    }
}
```

Comment: have u thought of setting likeCount default: 0 to avoid this problem? 1 less issue, 1 less search criterial = faster search

Comment: The database properties are based off of youtube-dl metadata which can have many different properties based on the website being downloaded from. I find it useful to separate 0 values from null values here so I don't have a ton of videos with null values appearing first (just because they came from a site that doesn't support likes) before I get the videos that don't have likes because they weren't liked.

Comment: You should be able to use $addFields to synthesize a field with non-null values (say, 0 or 1) based on the field you are sorting by and sort on that field first then on the field you want.

Comment: @D.SM How would I actually go about achieving that, while also filtering based on the search input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $set to synthesize a field with non-null values (say, 0 or 1) based on the field you are sorting by and sort on that field first then on the field you want:

```
var c = db['foo']
c.deleteMany({})
c.insertMany([{a:null,b:1},{a:2,b:2},{b:3},{a:4,b:4}])

e=c.aggregate([
  {$set: {a_type: {$type: '$a'}}},
  {$set: {s: {$cond: {if: {$in: ['$a_type',['null', 'missing']]}, then: 0, else: 1}}}},
  {$sort: {s: 1, a: 1}},
  {$project: {a_type: 0, s: 0}},
])
```

```
serene% mongo  --port 14400 <sort-null.js
MongoDB shell version v4.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:14400/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("139a14fa-1f46-42c0-b5f0-5ca7aa9ba762") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.2
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 4 }
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedIds" : [
        ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b81"),
        ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b82"),
        ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b83"),
        ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b84")
    ]
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b81"), "a" : null, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b83"), "b" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b82"), "a" : 2, "b" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6dadfd9d34e4e0b219b84"), "a" : 4, "b" : 4 }
bye
```

Comment: Worth noting that the answer does the opposite of what the question asks and makes null values always appear first. To fix this change the direction of the sort for `s`.